# How to fix System.InvalidOperationException in mvc 5 in index controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5, model

I'm learning to create a web application in  asp.net and following this documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

after completing all the step i'm getting this error and i don't know what to do with it

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to set database initializer of 
type 'Clothing_Store.DAL.CustomerInit, Clothing_Store' for DbContext type ' 
Clothing_Store.DAL.ShopContext, Clothing_Store' specified in the 
application configuration. See inner exception for details.'
```

InnerException:

```
InnerException  {"Could not load file or assembly 'Clothing_Store' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Clothing_Store"}    System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}
```

ShopContext:

```
using Clothing_Store.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Clothing_Store.DAL
{

    public class ShopContext: DbContext
    {
        public ShopContext() : base("ShopContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<customer> Customers { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }


}
```

CustomerInit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Clothing_Store.Models;

namespace Clothing_Store.DAL
{
    public class CustomerInit : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ShopContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ShopContext context)
        {
            var customers = new List<customer>
            {
                new customer{c_name="Carson",email="ab@g.com",pass="abcd",phone="012"},
                new customer{c_name="mason",email="abcd@g.com",pass="dabcd",phone="0122"}
            };
            customers.ForEach(s => context.Customers.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Clothing_Store-fefdc1f0-bd81-4ce9-b712-93a062e01031;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Clothing_Store-fefdc1f0-bd81-4ce9-b712-93a062e01031.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ShopContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Clothing_Store1;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Clothing_Store1.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type=" Clothing_Store.DAL.ShopContext, Clothing_Store">
        <databaseInitializer type="Clothing_Store.DAL.CustomerInit, Clothing_Store" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>

  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config`, there is an extra space added in the `<context type="`

```
<context type=" Clothing_Store.DAL.ShopContext, Clothing_Store">
               ^
```

Can you please remove that and re-run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to "rebuild" the application instead of using "build"? You can also try to "clean" the project first and then "build". Does the project "Clothing_Store" have the EntityFramework dlls? Also check if the Clothing_Store.dll is created in the \bin folder of the Asp.net MVC application.